# Unable to install nngraph using luarocks

Tags: torch, luarocks

When I tried to install nngraph using luarocks, I get the following error:

> Error: command 'install' requires exclusive write access to /usr/local - failed opening temp file /usr/local/.lock.tmp.78142522 for locking: /usr/local/.lock.tmp.78142522: Permission denied

The command I used:

```
luarocks install nngraph
```

I tried to look for solutions but could not find anything. I'm new to torch so any guidance will be much appreciated!